# Edit multiple HTML Files

Tags: html, text, automation, text-editor

I have 90 html files where an audio file is played (wrong link), I need to change the src of the audio file in each one of these files.

from

```
<embed src="../audio/" autostart=false width=0 height=0 id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
```

to:

file 1:

```
<embed src="../audio/1.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
```

file 2:

```
<embed src="../audio/2.mp3" autostart=false width=0 height=0 id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
```

...

Any suggestions for an automated approach? 
Thanks

Later edit:

The new src is different for each file... any possibilities to fill this automated for each file? for file1 -> src1, file2 -> src2 ...

Comment: What OS is this on? If it's *nix it seems like the sort of thing a bash script could do with, say, sed, for example.

Comment: Need this for Win OS, sed would have been great if I used *nix.

Comment: @Edd Cygwin is an option ... is sed working with Cygwin? hmm ... might  work

Comment: @thedev I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: found this: UnxUtils provides sed for Win32, as does GNUWin32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad ++ has some good search and replace functions you could use here.

Answer (score 2):

GNU sed is what you need: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/

Or eventually gawk: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/

Answer (score 1):

You use dreamweaver software to find replace all your files with your new audio name